# Type Error Django 3.0.4 : Typer Error while Runserver

Tags: django-views, django-templates

I am learning Django from clever programmer and have run into an issue.

I am trying to **./manage.py runserver and I run into a type error issue as provided on the below link

i assume there seems to be a problem on the line: `return render(request, 'movies/movies_stuff.html' , stuff_for_frontend)`

[TypeError - Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm1Q6.png)

**views.py_**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import movies

# Create your views here.
def Home_page(request):
user_query = str(request.GET.get('query' , ''))
search_result = movies.objects.filter(name__icontains=user_query)
stuff_for_frontend={'Search_result :', search_result}
return render(request, 'movies/movies_stuff.html' , stuff_for_frontend)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import include, path
from .views import Home_page

urlpatterns= [
path('', Home_page, name='Home _page')
]
```

**Templates-->movies-->movies_stuff.html**

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form action = "" name="search"  
            <input type= "text" name="query" value="{{request.GET.query}}"
            <input type =  "submit" value="Search" />
        {%for movies in search_result%}
        <p>{{movies.name}}</p>
        {% endfor %} 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is as it states, it's a type error. This is happening because the render method requires a dictionary and you are sending a set instead.Correct the following

```
stuff_for_frontend={'Search_result :', search_result} // this will become a set
```

to this

```
stuff_for_frontend={'Search_result' : search_result} // now a dictionary
```

The error occurs when try to access using keys on set. And in the template try to correct the form as I suspect it is incomplete.

Hope that helps! Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Corrected the Form and the Dictionary :) Its working now

Comment: @KarthikRSundar well if thats the solution you may mark the answer as accepted answer or upvoting helps !